Property of total internal reflection question
If I create a medium with gradually decreasing refractive index from once face at index 2.0 and other at 1.01, and show a beam of light upon the optically denser side, will there be any losses upon the light traveling within the layer of the medium?
Now imagine a reflecting body underneath the optically rarer face. When the light emerges from the rarer side and gets reflected by the body and falls back into the medium, will there be total internal reflection at the site of the 2.0 index face?

Mirage

If this reflecting body is in the index 2.0 medium, the reflected light is also in this medium. There can be total internal reflection depending on the direction of this reflected light. This depends on how the reflecting body is oriented and on the exact direction from which the incoming light is coming. You do not specify those things...

The Luneburg lens is almost exactly the scenario you are describing with the difference that the dielectric permittivity goes from $2$ to $1$ and the optical index is from $\sqrt{2}$ to $1$. It is a perfect imager in all direction and is used (its 2D version) as a wideband naval radar antenna, it can also be placed in a radiator to act as its wide angle primary aberration-free focusing mechanism. No total reflection because the index changes gradually as $n(r)=\sqrt{2-|\tfrac{r}{R}|^2}$  for a lens radius $R$.
